# iterate through object properties of type string c#

Tags: c#

i have an object "Person" with a long list of proprieties Name, City, Age, etc.
My goal is when i receive this object, to iterate throw the proprieties that are strings, and check if the strings have any special characters. My only problem here is the iteration part.
what i got so far (the iteration is wrong...)

```
public ActionResult Index(Person person)
{
    var haveSpecialCharacters = false;

    foreach (var property in typeof(Person).GetProperties())
    {
        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string) && !Validate(property))
        {
            haveSpecialCharacters = true;
            break;
        }
    }
 
 ...........
 ...........
}
```

Comment: You need to get the `MethodInfo` for the `getter` of the property.  Once you have that, you can `Invoke` the getter, getting the string (as an object) and doe whatever you want to it. Look at `PropertyInfo.GetGetMethod`

Comment: What problem are you having exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
bool IsPersonInvalid(Person person)
{
    bool HasSpecialCharacter(string value)
    {
        // Replace with something more useful.
        return value?.Contains("$") == true;
    }

    return typeof(Person)
        // Get all the public Person properties
        .GetProperties()
        // Only the ones of type string.
        .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        // Get the values of all the properties
        .Select(x => x.GetValue(person) as string)
        // Check any have special chars
        .Any(HasSpecialCharacter);
}

var person1 = new Person
{
    FirstName = "Bob$Bob",
    LastName = "Fred"
};
Console.WriteLine(IsPersonInvalid(person1)); // True

var person2 = new Person
{
    FirstName = "Bob",
    LastName = "Fred"
};
Console.WriteLine(IsPersonInvalid(person2)); // False
```